# Get rid of leading zeros in HTML input type="number"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, numbers

I have a regular input field with input HTML that allows users to enter a time range (minutes and seconds). From 5 seconds to 20 minutes.

However, there are error in the field that I would like to correct. As you can see, the field allows you to enter any number of zeros before the number. Please tell me how this situation can be handled so that the user can enter a maximum of two characters in the field? That is, the field would accept a value from the user in the format: 00 or 05 or 5 or 10. But do not allow 0000 or 00005 or 010.

```
    const limitValue = (min, max, val) => Math.min(max, Math.max(min, val));

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);
  const onInput = useCallback(
    (val, minutes) =>
      setValue((prev) =>
        limitValue(
          5,
          1200,
          minutes ? val * 60 + (prev % 60) : ~~(prev / 60) * 60 + val
        )
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        <input
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={20}
          value={~~(value / 60)}
          onInput={({ target: { value } }) => onInput(+value, true)}
        />
        m
      </span>
      <span>
        <input
          type="number"
          min={-1}
          max={60}
          value={value % 60}
          onInput={({ target: { value } }) => onInput(+value)}
        />
        s
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a terrible way to fix the problem (why I have no idea why it would be bad)... All I know is it works and I haven't noticed any real performance degredation by using it.
Wrap the value prop in parenthesees and call the .toString() method on both of your value props like this
`value={(~~(value / 60)).toString()}` and 
`value={(value % 60).toString()}` respectively.

This works because we are changing it to a string value which changes how 05 and 5 are perceived and therefore must be parsed back into the respective value... Which ultimately has the input rerender with the value you want.

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could change the value field of the first input as follows. Converting a number primitive to a string primitive will immediately chop off any leading zeros, and then you can pad back extra zeros.

```
value={(~~(value / 60)).toString().padStart(2, 0)}
```

Comment: Thanks to you too, but Sharp Dev's answer was earlier

Comment: That solution does not respect the following condition you requested: 'That is, the field would accept a value from the user in the format: 00 or 05'.

toString(), without padStart, removes all leading zeros meaning that 00 or 05 can't be generated.